# Sitecore site display page update

Tags: sitecore

I have a sitecore asp.mvc site.

The structure of content inside sitecore is like this:

```
> sitecore
    -->Content   
    ---->MySite  
    ------>Home  
    ------>Page1  
    ------>Page2
```

In sitecore configuration file, the startItem is MySite.

When I open `www.mysite.com` the MySite is displayed.

I want to display the Home subitem instead of MySite, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use [`IIS Rewrite` module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). Just set redirect or rewrite on root to `/Home`.

```
<rule name="Index Request" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/home" />
</rule>
```

if you want to stay on the `www.mysite.com` url but display home or

```
<rule name="Index Request" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/home" />
</rule>
```

if you want to redirect to `www.mysite.com/Home` url. In this case you may also think about having redirection layout / sublayout without installation of `IIS Redirect` module.

Comment: I've tried this but the rest of resources are not found. I would like to work with both urls: www.mysite.com and www.mysite.com/Home